# Find out if a process is using an Internet Connection

Tags: c#

Is it possible to find out if a particular application is using an Internet Connection using C#? Is there a library for this?

Basically something really simple, simpler than what wireshark does! Given a process id, I would get back if an Internet Connection was being used, what type i.e download or upload and at what rate.

Anything like this exist? Is it possible for me to throw something together to achieve this?

Comment: take  a look at here http://www.debugging.com/bug/2520

Comment: @pratapk you misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `netstat -ob` from a command prompt.

Comment: Interesting, any C# wrapper for this to help parse `netstat`?